# Multiplication error in MATLAB...ideas?

Tags: image, matlab

So I'm trying to do a full-scale contrast stretch to a grayscale image, and I'm getting some really strange answers. I've identified the problem, just not the solution.

Taking a test point, I(2,2) = 108.

```
(I(2,2) - 57)
```

Ans = 51, as you'd expect. Now here's the weird part:

```
(I(2,2) - 57)*255
```

Ans = 255.

If I do 51 * 255 explicitly, I get the correct answer (13005). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `uint8`, so its clipping at 255 (max for UINT8).

Comment: So how do I tell the program to not use uint8 for that line?

Comment: Convert it to `double` and then do those operations?

Comment: @rayryeng: That doesn't make it off-topic.  Either answer it or close it as a duplicate of another question about saturating arithmetic with MATLAB integral types.  Or just ignore it.  But don't close it with a reason that doesn't apply.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I understand.  My apologies.  I'll find a suitable duplicate then.

Comment: Do what @Divakar suggested and cast your array / image to double via `I = double(I);`, then do the calculations. You are undergoing what is known as clipping in MATLAB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771469/multipage-tiff-write-in-matlab-doesnt-work